# Is it safe to expose Okta clientId in a public repository?

Tags: angular, okta

To configure [Okta](https://developer.okta.com/) authentication in a Angular application it is needed to add a `config` variable with the settings for your `OIDC` app in the `app.module.ts` file. [source](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/08/22/basic-crud-angular-7-and-spring-boot-2)

```
const config = {
    issuer: 'https://dev-123456.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/implicit/callback',
    clientId: '{clientId}'
};
```

Where `{clientId}` is replaced by the actual `clientId`.

Pushing this application to a public repository would mean that the `clientId` is exposed for everyone to see. My question is if this forms any sort of security risk?

In my research I found a couple of similar questions with regards to the `apiKey` used by Firebase:

- [Is it safe to expose Firebase apiKey to the public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public)
- [Do you need to hide your Firebase API keys for Ionic apps?](https://javebratt.com/hide-firebase-api/)

In the case of Firebase there seems no harm in sharing the `apiKey`. But I'm not sure if Okta's `clientId` uses a similar principle?

I've also researched some public repositories on Github that implement Okta authentication. Most of those repositories seem to expose the `clientId` which makes me assume that there is no problem with sharing the `clientId`. Is this indeed the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There shouldn’t be any security issues with putting your Client ID in a GitHub repo. This value is similar to a license plate on a car. It’s just an identifier and is regularly passed in the URL for authorization requests.

The client secret is the value you don’t want to expose. It should NOT be stored in source control. I recommend storing a dummy value and overriding it with an environment variable.

Comment: Here is an [Okta dev forum post](https://devforum.okta.com/t/is-clientid-for-an-app-confidential/5841/2) agreeing that ClientID is safe to expose to the public.